# html forms - sending file to php with method post results in blank page

Tags: php, html

I have the following form:

```
<form name="uploadForm" action="proxy.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
                <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileInput" type="file"/>
                <input type="submit" name="uploadButton" value="Upload"/>  
</form>
```

The php works as a proxy and is OK (i do have to change the POST method to PUT in the proxy).
When upload is finished, the page turns blank and the path i see in the browser is the path to the php.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have appropriate level of Error_reporting (and error_display), to see if an error occurred? Also, you miss the value='' in file input

Comment: You need to post proxy.php if you want an answer not a guess

Comment: why do i need value= in the input?

Comment: The reason the page turns blank is because your submitting the form, if you want to make sure that you stay on the same page when the form is submitted you'll have to use ajax...

Answer (score 0):

after uploading the files in proxy.php redirect to the form page

```
//add  single line at last
header("Location:form.php");
```

Comment: I've formatted the code in your answer. If you want to do that yourself next time, there's a "pair of brackets" icon above the editor that'll format selected text as code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that i like is to post data in the same file:

```
<form name="uploadForm" action="?action=upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
                <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileInput" type="file"/>
                <input type="submit" name="uploadButton" value="Upload"/>  
</form>
```

at the beginning of your file that contains upload form, add this:

```
<?php
$uploadComplete = false;
     if(isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"]=="upload")
     {
          // put upload codes that you have in proxy.php
          $uploadComplete = true; // you can even set this variable to check if upload is done or not
     }
?>
```